# graphcool-framework deploy error 'ECONNREFUSED'

Tags: graphql, graphcool

I am getting an error in the GraphCool 5 minute tutorial https://www.graph.cool/docs/quickstart/frontend/react/apollo-tijghei9go

`graphcool-framework deploy`

Please choose the cluster you want to deploy to: `shared-ap-northeast-1`

Please choose the target name `prod`

Creating service server in cluster shared-ap-northeast-1... !
 ▸    'ECONNREFUSED': request to https://api.graph.cool/system failed,
 ▸    reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.33.35.222:443

A search didn't turn up much on the graphCool forums or here at stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

After taking some time away from the problem I realized I had installed graphcool locally first. When I got an error I then used npm to install graphcool globally.

Tonight I used npm to uninstall the local version.  The error went away!
I should have followed the tut exactly. Instead I tried to install dependencies locally because I read somewhere that installing them globally is not the preferred method anymore.